# maintaining sequence of batch commands

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing a script to power down a virtual machine, then copying the VM (since copying live leads to corruption), then doing some other tasks and finally restarting the VM.

However, since the vm is over 200gb, the bat file goes on to the next command before it is done copying the multiple files.  I have tried to use  Start /WAIT, but this opens a new cmd window that does not close after copying and does not return control to the main cmd window.  Calling one .bat file form the other has the same problem.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
RMDIR c:\Users\me\Documents\vmcopy\vcopy\VM /s /q

md c:\Users\me\Documents\vmcopy\vcopy\VM

xcopy C:\Users\me\"VirtualBox VMs"\VM C:\Users\me\Documents\vmcopy\vcopy\VM /e

cd c:\"Program Files"\Oracle\VirtualBox

Do other stuff that should done after copying
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your xcopy command has quotes in the wrong place. You would see an error message telling you this.

Comment: Incidentally, you can do those four moves in three, `@RD /S /Q "%UserProfile%\Documents\vmcopy\vcopy\VM"`, `@"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "%UserProfile%\VirtualBox VMs\VM" "%UserProfile%\Documents\vmcopy\vcopy\VM\" /E`, `@CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\Oracle\VirtualBox"`. With the trailing backslash on the destination, [tag:xcopy] will create the directory if it doesn't already exist. You could also use, _and I would recommend that you do_, [tag:robocopy] which superceded the outdated [tag:xcopy] as long ago as [tag:windows-vista]. Enter `robocopy /?` in a Command Prompt window for its usage information.

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions, which I will heed.  However, I am left with the main issue in my question, that is, how do I get the batch to wait for the robocopy command to finish?  As I say, I tried using /wait, but it di not work for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Batch files are essentially single threaded. Any command you execute needs to finish before the next command executes.  The code you have provided will not behave the way you are saying it is.

Comment: Your xcopy command ERRORED. So it was quick. It was waiting.

Comment: Mark, quoting just part of a path is fine. However, I think you're right -- XCOPY is bailing due to an error -- something the OP can and should be checking for via the ERRORLEVEL variable.